# Why is $\tan((1/2)\pi)$ undefined?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is the trigonometric function $\tan((1/2)\pi)$ undefined?

Comment: What is the definition of $\tan$ ?

Comment: If it were defined - what would it be?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189621/is-tan-pi-2-undefined-or-infinity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity that relates $\color{blue}{\tan}$ with $\color{red}{\sin}$ and $\color{green}{\cos}$ is: $$\color{blue}{\tan}(\alpha)=\frac{\color{red}{\sin}(\alpha)}{\color{green}{\cos}(\alpha)}\tag{1}$$

and $\color{green}{\cos}\color{black}{(}\pi/2\color{black})=0$, adding to it the fact that division by zero is undefined, it follows that $\color{blue}{\tan}(\pi/2)$ is undefined.

---

Furthermore, since $\color{green}{\cos}\left(n\pi-\pi/2\right)=0$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z$ , we conclude from $\text{(1)}$ that for every $n\in\Bbb Z$, $\color{blue}{\tan}(n\pi-\pi/2)$ is undefined.

Comment: Typo in your last $\tan$

Comment: Fixed, thanks @DanielLittlewood .

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer that is not really about division by $0$. $\tan(\alpha)$ is the length of the line segment that is tangent to the unit circle in the image below. So what would happen to this length if $\alpha$ were $\pi/2$?

[image]

Note this diagram works for all nonvertical angles as long as you interpret the "length" of the tangent segment as negative if it ends up on the lower side, and also as long as you are willing to pull back rays from obtuse angles until they intersect that vertical line there.

It's debatable that $\tan(x)$ is *defined* as $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$, as some other answers suggest. I think its name suggests that its original definition is more like what we see in this diagram: something about a *tangent* line. It just *happens to be equal* to $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ because of similar triangle ratios. Similarly, $\sec(x)$ is the length of the hypotenuse in this picture, and a *secant* line is any line that cuts through a curve, like the hypotenuse here cuts through the circle.

Answer (score 2):

Because $\tan(x)$ is defined as being equal to $\sin(x)/\cos(x)$, and $\cos(\pi/2)=0$. So $\tan(\pi/2)=1/0$, which is undefined because of the division by zero.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can see that 
$$\tan x:= \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$
and it's known that $\sin \frac{\pi}{2}=1$ and $\cos \frac{\pi}{2}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A feature not explained in other answers is that you can't define the tan function as simply "infinite" at the point of discontinuity. From one side it is unboundedly positive, and from the other unboundedly negative.

Comment: It will have to take values in $P^1$ then ;)