# Calculating righ/left sided limits

Tags: limits

For example, limit of cos(x)/sin(x) as x approaches pi from right/left... how does one do it, rigourously, instead of just evaluating the function at x = something just to the left of Pi, and x = something just to the right of pi?

Comment: Maybe this is of interest to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189621/is-tan-pi-2-undefined-or-infinity

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively consider how behave numerator and denominator when $x$ approaches $\pi$ and conclude.

Another way is to consider Taylor series built at $x=\pi$. You have $$\cot(x)=\frac{1}{x-\pi }-\frac{x-\pi }{3}+O\left((x-\pi )^3\right)$$ from which you can conclude.

I am sure that you can take from here.

If you consider Taylor series built at $x=\pi$  for numerator and denominator , you have $$\cos(x)=-1+\frac{1}{2} (x-\pi )^2+O\left((x-\pi )^4\right)$$ $$\sin(x)=-(x-\pi )+\frac{1}{6} (x-\pi )^3+O\left((x-\pi )^4\right)$$ to arrive to the same conclusions.

Comment: Strictly spoken, this is a Laurent series; a Taylor series does not allow negative powers of $x$.

Comment: @AlexR. You are very correct ... but it could just be a question of semantics. Let me say that I computed the Taylor series of $(x-\pi) \cot(x)$ at $x=\pi$.

Comment: That's of course also valid, but I suppose you knew we had a pole of first order at $x=\pi$ beforehand so that $(x-\pi)\cot x$ is defined at $x=\pi$.

Comment: @AlexR. Again, you are totally right. It is always good to argue. This is how we arrive to ***Fiat lux***. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So our limit is:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \lim_{x\to\pi} \cot x$$

From the right:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi^{+}} \cot x$$

As $x\to\pi^{+}$, $\cot x \to\infty$

And as $x\to\pi^{-}$, $\cot x \to-\infty$

Therefore, since the left and right limits don't exist, the limit doesn't exist.

Prove this using the graph of $\cot x$.