# $\operatorname{Arctg}(a) + \operatorname{Arctg}(b)$ when $a b =1$

Tags: trigonometry

As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724348/what-is-arctanx-arctany) it is known that one can write $\operatorname{Arctg}(a) + \operatorname{Arctg}(b)$ as a form of $\operatorname{Arctg}\frac{a+b}{1- a\: b}$ plus a constant in the case where $a \:b<1$ or $a \:b>1$. I am wondering what happens when $a b=1$. Is there  a formula for this case?

Comment: Carefully think about what it means if $$\tan u=\frac1{\tan v}=\cot v=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-v\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your comment shows that it is equal to $\pi/2$ but I think it could also be equal to $-\pi/2$ am I write? @J.M.isapoormathematician

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that
$$\arctan x+\arctan\frac1x= \begin{cases}\phantom{-}\dfrac\pi 2&\text{if } x>0,\\[0.5ex]-\dfrac\pi 2  &\text{if } x<0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: I am not sure, because one can, for example, consider $a= \frac{p+c}{t}$ and $b=\frac{t}{p+c}$, if $p=-c$ the answer to my question is not clear

Comment: This is the case $x=0$, which I do not consider ($\frac1x$ is not defined).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> $ab = 1 \rightarrow a = b = 1$, so
>
> $$\arctan (1) + \arctan (1) = \dfrac {1+1}{1-1} \rightarrow \dfrac 2 0 $$

Since $\dfrac 2 0$ is undefined, then

> $$\arctan \dfrac 2 0 = \dfrac \pi 2.$$

Also, since $\arctan 1 = \dfrac {\pi}{4}$,

> $$\arctan 1 + \arctan 1 = \dfrac \pi 4 + \dfrac \pi 4 = \dfrac \pi 2.$$

In other words, you can define the behavior of $\arctan (a) + \arctan (b)$ as follows:

> $$\arctan (a)+\arctan(b)= \begin{cases}\phantom{-}\dfrac{a+b}{1-ab}&\text{if } a \neq b,\\[0.5ex]\phantom {-}\dfrac \pi 2  &\text{if } a=b.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Also, in the case that I mentioned in the comment for the other answer, it is still not clear

Comment: What don't you get about dividing by $0$?

Comment: Also see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665410/finding-the-possible-values-of-y-tanx/2665446#2665446

Comment: What if I have $a=\frac{p+c}{d}$ and $b=\frac{d}{p+c}$ and $p=-c$?

Comment: See @Bernard's response below mine.