# Is $\tan90°$ undefined or is it positive infinity?

Tags: trigonometry

I can understand why $${\lim_{θ \to 90}  \tan(θ) = ∞}$$

But since $$\tan90°=\frac{\sin90°}{\cos90°}$$

which results in $\frac{1}{0}$, I get confused, as $\frac{1}{0}$ could be both positive and negative infinity, which is one of the ways I think of its undefined nature. In such case, why do we consider the positive infinity scenario?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: $\cos 90^\circ=0$, so the result of dividing by it is undefined in the real numbers

Comment: $\lim\limits_{\theta\to{90^\circ}^-}\tan\theta=+\infty$, $\lim\limits_{\theta\to{90^\circ}^+}\tan\theta=-\infty$,

Comment: It's not positive infinity, rather just "infinity".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line

Comment: $\lim_{\theta\to 90^{\circ}}\tan(\theta)$ is not $+\infty$. If $\theta > 90^{\circ}$, $\cos(\theta) < 0$, so from the left the limit is $+\infty$, but from the right the limit is $-\infty$. This limit does not exist in possibly the most extreme way.

Comment: The use of $\infty$ in a limit equation is shorthand for saying the value gets arbitrarily large as the argument approaches the specified thing. Infinity is not a number and one needs to be careful discussing it in an arithmetic way.

Comment: As others note, you must be careful about *left-hand* and *right-hand* limits. Be that as it may ... If someone were to compose, say, [a geometrically-flavored introduction to the trig functions (PDF link)](https://tricochet.com/math/pdfs/AlmostEverythingAboutTrig.pdf) that restricts discussion to first-quadrant angles only, then it would be perfectly reasonable to think of $\tan 90^\circ$ as $+\infty$ to help promote an intuitive understanding of the behavior of $\tan\theta$ *in that restricted context*. Of course, once other quadrants come into view, that thinking would need to be refined.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined, and same is the case with $\tan 90^{\circ}$.

To show why, use the definition of division. It says $\frac{a}{b}=c$ when $a=bc$ holds and $a$ is unique when $b,c$ are kept fixed. But note that in case of $0$, you have $a \cdot 0= c$ holds whenever you set $c=0$ and $a\in \mathbb{N}$, a contradiction to uniqueness.

Comment: You might think of it with limits and stuffs as mentioned in comments, but i would like to be basic

Answer (score 0):

If $\theta$ *is exactly* $90^\circ$, then $\tan \theta$ is undefined because of division by zero.

If $\theta$ *tends to* $90^\circ$, namely $\theta -90^\circ$ is (non-zero) infinitesimal, then $\tan\theta=\infty$.

You said:

> as $\frac{1}{0}$ could be both positive and negative infinity

This is correct only when you clearly understand its meaning. $\frac{1}{0}$ is **not** valid *as an arithmetic expression*, it is only valid *as a symbol*, denoting that the numerator tends to $1$ and the denominator is infinitesimal. Just as when we speak of a "$\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate", we actually mean the limit status of an expression of the form $\frac{\text{infinitesimal}}{\text{infinitesimal}}$.

Answer (score 0):

I put an answer here a couple of years ago that may help: [Finding the Possible Values of y = tan(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665410/finding-the-possible-values-of-y-tanx/2665446#2665446).

The gist: as $\theta \rightarrow \dfrac {\pi}{2}$, the values grow to $\infty$ *except* for $\dfrac {\pi}{2}$.

$\tan \dfrac {\pi}{2}$ is undefined due to the definition of tangent, i.e.  $\dfrac {\sin \frac {\pi}{2}}{\cos \frac {\pi}{2}} = \dfrac {1}{0}$ (and similarly for $\dfrac {3\pi}{2}$, except $\sin \dfrac {3 \pi}{2}$ is $-1$).